# 502 Bad Gateway Error with my 4 websites hosted on single VPS

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-7.1

I have 4 websites hosted on the vps, and recently all the website start showing 502 bad gateway error.

I have done the following things to troubleshoot but the problem still persists.

1. set the `fastcgi_read_timeout` in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
2. replaces  `/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock`  to `127.0.0.1:9000` in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d`

Answer (score 0):

try hard-restarting nginx and look at the nginx.error.log and the nginx logs for your sites.

if that doesn't fix it, what changed? you upload new code? php updated? someone hack your vps?

Comment: Finally solved, did a silly mistake at /etc/nginx/sites-available/default we need to replace unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock with 127.0.0.1:9000 but I replaced only /var/run/php5-fpm.sock with 127.0.0.1:9000